# cf cli login: How to omit the -o parameter without stopping the batch script?

Tags: command-line-interface, cfml

If I omit the -o parameter of the cf login, the batch script stops to select one of the specified orgs. To skip the selection I have to press enter.
How can I omit the -o parameter without stopping the batch script? Or to make the script continuous run automatically.

Background: normally I don't know anything about the activated CF orgs of a specific user. I want to run a loop over the orgs in a later step to find out. But for this I have to log in to cf cli first.

I have already tried the following:

echo -ne '\n' | cf login ...

Doesn't work -> error message: org "-ne '\n' " not found...

Any ideas?

BR,
Illya

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem myself:
Since I use it in the context of SAP BTP, I can get the name of the CF orgs via a btp cli command.
CF is an environment instance in SAP BTP, so

```
btp list accounts/environment-instance --subaccount ID
```

then

```
btp get accounts/environment-instance ID --subaccount sa-id
```

The information under label gives the name of the CF org.

Next is to use a dummy name for the cf login for the -s space parameter. If the space exist - fine. If the space doesn't exist - it doesn't matter, since the -o org parameter is correct and will let you signed in anyway.